# How to work with printed Pandas Dataframe output?

Tags: python, pandas

What's the easies way to make a `pandas dataframe` from printed `pandas dataframe output`?

**Context:** Many questions on StackOverflow are asked together with data looking like this:

```
index   count1   count2   diff
A       1        0        1
B       1        2        -1
C       1        2        -1
D       0        2        -2
```

I want to run the persons (in this case hypothetical) code with the data. What's the fastest/easiest way to load this data into Pandas?

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: @Brendan This might be something like what I'm looking for, but this takes a string of CSV, correct? Then I need to convert the data to CSV first.

Comment: Try it, seems to work fine on your example (you can also specify separator/delimiter in `read_clipboard`). The only issue I sometime run into using this is column names/values with whitespaces in them (pandas finding more values in row than it should)

Comment: I got it working! It worked differently than I expected! How cool that it takes the contents of the clipboard like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Before I learned today about `read_clipboard()` from @Brendan's comment above, I used to do this:

```
text = """index   count1   count2   diff
A       1        0        1
B       1        2        -1
C       1        2        -1
D       0        2        -2"""
data = np.array(list(text.split())).reshape(5, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```